# Issue with the size of the .cod file

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to add more png images to my app. When the size of the .cod file crosses 5mb it throws a runtime exception, and I cannot figure why, even with a debugger. If I remove some images I can run the app.  I am using BlackBerry OS 4.7 with the storm.  Later OS versions also have the same issue.

Comment: How do you install the app (OTA or smth else)? Do you use a real device or a simulator? Do you have this only on Storm 4.7?

Comment: I am checking the app in simulator. Not only in 4.7, it is on higher versioins also.

Comment: Not sure, but probably you app exceeds the limit, check this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/502534 . In this case you may try (1) to use a library project or (2) implement "lazy resource loading" (images are downloaded on the first app start and are saved on the SDCard for further usage).

Comment: Hi Arhimed thanks for your suggestion.How to do lazy resource loading? When I am taking all the images before main method I move the images to SDCard.But it is throwing same runtimeexception and I cannot compile it.

Comment: I responded via a normal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi Arhimed thanks for your
>   suggestion.How to do lazy resource
>   loading? When I am taking all the
>   images before main method I move the
>   images to SDCard.But it is throwing
>   same runtimeexception and I cannot
>   compile it.

Under the "lazy resource loading" I mean you could host your images somewhere in the internet. So on the first app start, being under a splash screen, you would download them to SDCard (or to Device Memory if Device Memory is big enough - it is fully up to you where to store the images). On a slow connection it could take minutes, so you definitely need to inform users about what is going on, so they don't think the app has hung.

Comment: Yes that is fine Arhimed, but as per requirements of the app I need to take the images locally and use them in the application.

Comment: If you have images on device file system, then you can use them inside of your app. You can create an EncodedImage/Bitmap/BitmapField from an image file. I don't see any reason why you can not do that. I believe lots of gaming apps follow this approach.

Comment: Yeah I used Bitmap to display on to the screen.When I  take all required image files then the size of cod file get increase and cannot compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use OTA in Following command on Application folder.
cd application dir.....
ren appName.cod *.zip // this will divided one cod file to multiple part it.
and now you can extract this zip file on specific folder and also add it's .jad file